# DynaTable Official Website is Down

Tags: dynatable

I just started using dynatables and am still heavily dependent on examples from https://www.dynatable.com/.  Unfortunately the site is down with the following message:

**You have requested a site that is currently offline. This generally happens when a site is temporarily disabled for some reason, but has not been permanently removed.
If you are one of our members and you expected to see your site here, please visit our Member Home Page and check the following:
Make sure your site is enabled.
Make sure you have funds on deposit.
Try the Site Troubleshooting Wizard.
Submit a Secure Support Request for assistance.
If you are not the member of our service who owns this site, please don't ask us about it. We have a very strict privacy policy and won't be able to tell you anything.**

Does anybody know if the site is really just down temporarily, or if it's gone for good? I'm asking here because on the dynatable github site it says to ask questions here with and to use the dynatable tag...

Answer (score 0):

And like that, the site is back up...guess it really was just temporary....

Answer (score 0):

Its down again, same message, I'm using Google Cache